# Copy one file content (data) to other file file in the specific area using python Logic

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I Have the good experience in C programming languange and started to work on python with the C Backround.

We have the file with Names for Example 1.txt and 2.txt. i am taking  all the Content of 1.txt and writing in to 2.txt from the given line number and the all the lines in 2.txt will be moved down automtically - For this i am using below logic:

```
f = open("1.txt", "r")
contents = f.readlines()
f.close()

with open("2.txt") as f:
    data = f.read().rstrip("\n")   

line =19
contents.insert(line, data)

f = open("1.txt", "w")
contents = "".join(contents)
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```

This logic is working very well but the Problem which i am facing is the last line is written immideatly after the 1.txt Content. ( But as per my requiremnt it is has to start form next line) even i tried with "\n" but i am not able to achive.

For more clarity like below.

1.txt :

```
   hello
    hello
    hello
    hello
```

2.txt:

```
123
456
789
451
234
```

suppose if i execute my code for the above 1.txt and 2.txt files ( and i want to write my data between 789 and 451).

after executing script the 2.txt Looks like below:

```
123
456
789
hello
hello
hello
hello 451
234
```

Here "Hello 451" is making my logic not to work next time.

So i want to achive like below:

```
123
456
789
hello
hello
hello
hello 
451
```

Please kinldy share the solution or guide me to achive this logic.
234

Comment: You are removing the newline character when you do `data = f.read().rstrip("\n")`. Try ***NOT*** stripping the newline and see what happens: `data = f.read()`.

Comment: Or strip all the newlines asap when reading, and add them back when writing the file again.

Comment: Just now i tried as you suggested data = f.read() but the behaviour is still same...

Answer (score 0):

I made one change in the code and it worked for me

Replace the line : `contents.insert(line, data)` with  : `contents.insert(line, data+"\n")`